# Apache hitting 90-100% on ubuntu "top", how do I find what's causing the extra cpu cycles?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress

My webstie is slow and I'm trying to troubleshoot the backend.

On an article page the cpu is hitting ~100%.

I'm using ubuntu/Apache and I'm viewing the stats using top.

The process hogging the cpu is giving me a pid number but is that just apache's number or can I track down a more specific process that is causing the cpu cycles?

If so how?

Comment: Install htop and recheck, htop gives better output than the ordinary top

Comment: $apt-get install htop

Comment: You may also want to have a look on this video <http://training.linuxfoundation.org/free-linux-training/linux-training-videos/linux-performance-analysis-with-perf>

Comment: @Ahmadgeo Thanks, but that page has moved apparently.

Comment: Sorry; here is the correct one http://training.linuxfoundation.org/free-linux-training/linux-training-videos/linux-performance-analysis-with-perf

Comment: or https://video.linux.com/media/com_lfvideos/videos/linux-tutorial-performance-analysis-with-perf-1337273347/perf-tutorial.mp4

Comment: @Ahmadgeo htop is much better than top, thanks. I figured it out anyway, it was some javascript repeatedly calling admin-ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I've used newrelic monitoring tool to trace specific resource consuming web requests. New relic monitors all apache transaction. It's a paid tool but you can use 14 days trial account.

[**`http://www.newrelic.com/`**](http://www.newrelic.com/)

Comment: I'm actually using relic already but I haven't really looked into it much, I didn't realize it was that thorough.